# Distribution of Records using SQL

Tags: sql-server

How to proper distributed SKU per Site. All Site must have SKUS whether there is a quantity or not. Please refer on below table

```
DocNos  SKU  SiteCode  Site         Qty
2222    AAA  001       Eastwood      1
2222    BBB  002       Holywood      2
2222    BBB  003       Baywood       1
2222    CCC  004       RiverBank     3
2222    AAA  004       RiverBank     3
```

On example on Site Eastwood only SKU AAA was allocated on this site, however we need to include other SKU (BBB, CCC) on this site but only 0 allocation.

Desired Output

```
DocNos  SKU  SiteCode  Site         Qty
2222    AAA  001       Eastwood      1
2222    BBB  001       Eastwood      0
2222    CCC  001       Eastwood      0
2222    BBB  002       Holywood      2
2222    AAA  002       Holywood      0
2222    CCC  002       Holywood      0
2222    BBB  003       Baywood       1
2222    AAA  003       Baywood       0
2222    CCC  003       Baywood       0
2222    CCC  004       RiverBank     3
2222    AAA  004       RiverBank     3
2222    BBB  004       RiverBank     0
```

Comment: Do you have an existing table with all SKU's listed? If so you can use an `outer join`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with help of row_number in sql.

Here is code for your reference.

```
CREATE TABLE #recipes (
DocNos INT ,
SKU VARCHAR(30) ,
SiteCode VARCHAR(30) ,
Site VARCHAR(30) ,
Qty  INT ,
);

INSERT INTO #recipes VALUES     (2222,'AAA','001','Eastwood',1)
INSERT INTO #recipes VALUES     (2222,'BBB','002','Holywood',2)
INSERT INTO #recipes VALUES     (2222,'AAA','002','Holywood',0)
INSERT INTO #recipes VALUES     (2222,'BBB','001','Eastwood',0)

select * from #recipes

SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Site ORDER BY Qty desc)  AS rownum,
DocNos, SKU, SiteCode, Site,Qty FROM #recipes
```

I hope it will work for you.

Thank You :)

Comment: i think this will not  give expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this. Create CTE's and then cross join and left join:

**Test data:**

```
create table test(docnos int, SKU varchar(3), sitecode varchar(3), site varchar(20), qty int);
insert into test values (2222, 'AAA', '001', 'Eastwood', 1);
insert into test values (2222, 'BBB', '002', 'Holywood', 2);
insert into test values (2222, 'BBB', '003', 'Baywood', 1);
insert into test values (2222, 'CCC', '004', 'RiverBank', 3);
insert into test values (2222, 'AAA', '004', 'RiverBank', 3);

with cteUniqueSKU (SKU) as (select distinct sku from test),
cteUniqueSite(Sitecode) as (select distinct sitecode from test),
cteCounts (docnos, site, qty, sku, sitecode) as (select docnos, site, qty, sku, sitecode from test)

select c.docnos, t.SKU, g.sitecode, c.site, coalesce (c.qty, 0)
from cteUniqueSKU as t cross join cteUniqueSite as g
left join cteCounts as c on c.sitecode = g.sitecode and c.sku = t.sku
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be as a comment but due to large text content, posting an answer will delete later:

Note: This is not the expected output what you want but you can work on this query to get the expected output,

Sample query to generate data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
DocNos INT ,
SKU VARCHAR(30) ,
SiteCode VARCHAR(30) ,
Site VARCHAR(30) ,
Qty  INT ,
);

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES     (2222,'AAA','001','Eastwood ',1)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES     (2222,'BBB','002','Holywood ',2)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES     (2222,'BBB','003','Baywood  ',1)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES     (2222,'CCC','004','RiverBank',3)
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES     (2222,'AAA','004','RiverBank',3)
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU 
INTO #ALLSKU
FROM #temp


SELECT B.DocNos,B.SKU,B.SiteCode,B.Site,B.Qty
INTO #CJ
FROM #temp B
CROSS JOIN #ALLSKU


SELECT A.* 
FROM 
#CJ A
JOIN #temp B ON B.SKU = A.SKU AND B.SiteCode = A.SiteCode
```

Current Output:

```
DocNos  SKU SiteCode    Site    Qty
2222    AAA 001       Eastwood  1
2222    BBB 002       Holywood  2
2222    BBB 003       Baywood   1
2222    CCC 004       RiverBank 3
2222    AAA 004       RiverBank 3
2222    AAA 001       Eastwood  1
2222    BBB 002       Holywood  2
2222    BBB 003       Baywood   1
2222    CCC 004       RiverBank 3
2222    AAA 004       RiverBank 3
2222    AAA 001       Eastwood  1
2222    BBB 002       Holywood  2
2222    BBB 003       Baywood   1
2222    CCC 004       RiverBank 3
2222    AAA 004       RiverBank 3
```